# How to manage server configurations for small projects and servers?

Tags: linux, user-management, package-management

I have been developing a web application which recently launched. Now I am continuing with improvements and want to create a staging server similar to the production server.

I know of the existence of tools like Ansible, Puppet and Chef, however scanning through the docs seems like they are a bit overkill for my simple usecase. Of course there is the solution of completely dockerizing the application, which would be a good thing.

But other than Dockerizing the application, what would you recommend for simply recreating a production server?

All it has to do is:

- Install a few dependencies: PHP, MySQL, Nginx, Java, Elasticsearch
- Add database, database user
- Add a user
- Configure SSH keys
- Change SSH to authorization by keyfile only
- Add a few firewall rules

Comment: I actually love Ansible for stuff like this. A single text file with human-readable steps, and Vagrant supports it as a provisioner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually puppet has a very easy to implement local config for small environments and is one of the best tools for this.

This page has info on a very very quick and easy setup.

http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/simplest_puppet_install_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer - much opinion herein.

With that out of the way, my first question would be, "How big will this application become?" If the answer is >10 servers, I'd suggest biting the bullet and going the Puppet/Chef/Ansible route. If <10 servers, just reproduce manually looking at package manifests, and taking notes as you build your second server.